# Using HTML form field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using jQuery Mobile and am attempting to use HTML5 form field validation to perform inline form field validation.  I am doing this because I really like the way that the browser reports issues in the bubble and I don't think it is very user friendly to wait until someone has completed filling out a form and then tell them what is wrong.  Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="frmMain" action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" data-enhance="false" value="1" id="cbxFB" />
    <label for="cbxFB">
        <span class="formsubtext">Check this box to use Facebook information to help fill out this registration.  Once registered you will be able to use the Facebook login button.</span>
    </label>

    <label for="tbEmail">*Email</label><input type="email" id="tbEmail" required autofocus placeholder="example@address.com" />
    <label for="tbPassword">*Password</label><input type="password" id="tbPassword" required />
    <div class="formsubtext" style="margin-top:1px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px">Minimum of 6 characters, one capital character, and one lower case character.</div>
    <label for="tbPasswordConfirm">*Password Confirm</label><input type="password" id="tbPasswordConfirm" required />

    <label for="tbPin">*Account Pin</label><input type="password" pattern="[0-9]{4}" id="tbPin" required placeholder="####" />
    <div class="formsubtext" style="margin-top:1px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px">A four digit number that you will remember.  This value will be needed to perform sensitive tasks within the application.</div>

    <label for="tbFName">*First Name</label><input type="text" id="tbFName" required />
    <label for="tbLName">*Last Name</label><input type="text" id="tbLName" required />
    <label for="tbPhone">Phone Number</label><input type="tel" id="tbPhone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" style="margin-bottom:1px; padding-bottom:0px;" />
    <div class="formsubtext" style="margin-top:1px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:20px;">Used at your option when you schedule an appointment with a service provider</div>

    <div style="display:none;"><label for="tbfbID">Facebook ID</label><input type="text" id="tbfbID" /></div>

    <input type="submit" id="btnMainNext" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" value="Next" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn-c ui-btn ui-corner-all" />
</form>
```

For the confirm password form field I have the following event defined:

```
$("#tbPasswordConfirm").on("change", function (event) {
  var password = $("#tbPassword").val();
  var passwordconfirm = $("#tbPasswordConfirm").val();

  if (password != passwordconfirm) {
    $("#tbPasswordConfirm")[0].setCustomValidity("The value entered does not match the previous password entered.");
    $("#btnMainNext").click();
  }
  else {
    $("#tbPasswordConfirm")[0].setCustomValidity("");
  }
  $(this).focus().select();
})
```

My problem is that when the user enters something into the field and moves to the next field the HTML form validation shows the error message for the next field (which is required).  I want it to show the message for the field they just left.  How do I stop the focus from moving to the next field so that the bubble message that shows up is from the field they just entered the data into?  As you can see I have tried setting the focus but that does not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems you should not do `$("#btnMainNext").click();` Why not do onkeyup instead?

Comment: instead of `$(this).focus` howabout `$('#tbPasswordConfirm').focus()`

Comment: @billy Why? $(this) IS #tbPasswordConfirm

Comment: @mplungjan - The call to the click of the button is what actually fires the form validation.   That button is the submit button and if you call the submit function directly the validation does not fire so you have to simulate someone clicking the submit button.

Comment: @billy - I have tried using the id like you suggest with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/akt4h8tm/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#tbPasswordConfirm").on("input", function(event) {
    var thisField = $("#tbPasswordConfirm")[0],
      theForm = $("#frmMain")[0],
      password = $("#tbPassword").val(),
      passwordconfirm = $(this).val(),
      custom = password === passwordconfirm ? "" : "The value entered does not match the previous password entered.";
    thisField.setCustomValidity(custom);
    if (!theForm.checkValidity()) theForm.reportValidity();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that the validation never gets fired until the form is submitted.  so what I did was in the change event fired the click of the submit button but it seems to have the same result as what I was doing.  Focus moves to the next field and that field's message pops up.

Comment: I tried it but the checkValidity call has no effect when called.  I don't remember why but for some reason I remember that you have to simulate a submit of the form through the click of a submit button.

Comment: I now know how. the checkValidity will return the error, then we can reportValidity. See update

Comment: It does not like the theForm.reportValidity().  Tells me "Object doesn't support property or method 'reportValidity'"  I looked and see the function does exist on the form but it does not like it.  Another issue is that since the input event fires as soon as I start typing and I assume on every keystroke wouldn't that show the error while they were still typing?

Comment: Yes and in my Chrome it skips to the next field when the passwords match

Answer (score 0):

**You can stop focus from moving to the next field but you can't trigger native validation UI or error message unless you click submit button.**

To stop focus from moving next field, after you set the custom validity on the field, you can use:

```
$('#tbPasswordConfirm').blur(function(event) {
    event.target.checkValidity();
}).bind('invalid', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(event.target).focus();}, 50);
});
```

The `blur()` function will check the validity on blur and if it would be invalid, the corresponding function in `bind()` would set the focus back to that element.

Comment: So that worked at keeping focus in the field.  What I have done is combined this with what mplungjan had provide and then in the change event I fire the click for the submit button.  This gives me what I am looking for with one minor detail.  After I set the validity of any field to invalid anytime a field gains focus the bubble help with it's validation is displayed.  How can I reset the form validity?  By the way thank you to everyone that has helped with this.  I have been noodling on it for a couple of days and could not come up with a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use html `tabindex` attr to manipulate which element will get the focus when you click tab character. See [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) to how to use it.

For example, if you make your password confirm input as `tabindex="5"`, you can add `tabindex="6"` to the `<label for="tbPin">` element to prevent next input from focusing right after.

Comment: I tried this but it still shows the validation message for the next field.  Since this is on a mobile device the tab for the label is skipped because it is basically the same as someone clicking on each field to enter data.  I know that I mis-spoke in my problem and used the phrase "tab".  Sorry force of habit.

Comment: I think it can still work. The problem can be that label has `for` attr. So, just try to give the `tabindex="6"` to another independent element.